# Efficiently sorting a String by the number of occurrences of each of its characters

Tags: java, string, performance, sorting

I'm trying to sort a string by the number of occurrences of each of its characters, with the most frequent at the beginning and rarest at the end. After sorting, I would need to remove all the character repeats. Because examples are always clearer, the program should do the following:

```
String str = "aebbaaahhhhhhaabbbccdfffeegh";
String output = sortByCharacterOccurrencesAndTrim(str);
```

In this case, the 'sortByCharacterOccurrencesAndTrim' method should return:

```
String output = "habefcdg"
```

In the case where 2 characters have the same occurrence, their order in the returned string doesn't matter. So "habefcdg" can also equal "habfecgd", because both 'f' and 'e' occur 3 times and both 'd' and 'g' occur once.

```
"habefcdg" would effectively be the same as "habfecgd"
```

***Note:*** I would like to point out that *performance matters* in this case, so I would prefer the most efficient method possible. I say this because the string length can range from 1 to the max length (which I think is the same as Integer.MAX_VALUE, but not sure), so I want to minimize any potential bottlenecks.

Comment: Is there a limited set of characters?

Comment: If the string is too large then using maps would be a good option in terms of performance as map can sort easily with the help of hashcode.

Comment: @shmosel The string is encoded with US_ASCII, so any available ascii character.

Comment: Please define "unreasonable amount of time". I can process a 100,000,000-character string using maps in **~215ms**. Using array as [suggested by Jim Mischel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39783566/5221149), it takes **~48ms**. Using Streams as [suggested by Óscar López](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39783734/5221149) takes **~1250ms**. Even the comparatively slow Stream solution is not taking an "*unreasonable* amount of time", in my opinion.

Comment: @Andreas My apologies. I had originally tested with some strewn-together code that involved 1 for-loop and a repeated regex calls, so I think a majority of the time was in my clumsiness. In terms of timing, would the Streams approach be any better is the stream ran in parallel?

Comment: Yes, with parallel it dropped to **~400ms**.

Comment: Does your string potentially contain Asian languages? If so, note that you can't treat Java chars independently; you need to take into account surrogate pairs and allow for far more than 65k distinct characters, making an array-based solution impractical.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Even taking in account non-BMP code points, the number of total Unicode code points is only 17 times 65k - I would say the array solution could remain practical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"A map and several while loops" is certainly the easiest way to go, and probably would be very fast. The idea is:

```
for each character
    increment its count in the map
Sort the map in descending order
Output the map keys in that order
```

But 100,000,000 map lookups could get pretty expensive. You could potentially speed it up by creating an array of 65,536 integer counts (or 128 characters if it's ASCII). Then:

```
for each character
    array[(int)ch] += 1
```

Then, you go through that array and create a map of the characters with non-zero counts:

```
for i = 0 to 65535
    if array[i] > 0
        map.add((char)i, array[i])
```

Then sort the map in descending order and output the characters in that order.

That could perform quite a bit faster, simply because indexing into an array 100,000,000 times is likely a lot faster than doing 100,000,000 map lookups.

Comment: `HashMap` lookups are _O(1)_, so why do you say array lookups would "perform quite a bit faster" than map lookups?

Comment: @Andreas: A lookup is O(1), yes. So is indexing an array directly. But remember O(1) doesn't take constant factors into account. Indexing into an array involves an indirect memory reference. Looking up in a hash map involves calling a function that computes a hash value from the key and then indexes into the backing array. A hash table lookup is, asymptotically as fast as indexing into an array, but requires a whole lot more code to be executed.

Comment: I tested performance of your solutions. See [my comment to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783311/39783734#comment66861860_39783311). Relatively speaking, a 4x performance difference can be considered "pretty expensive", but both solutions still run pretty fast for a 100,000,000-character string.

Comment: @Andreas: The simple map solution certainly seems like the way to go. My array solution is faster, but I don't think 50 msec is going to matter that much when you take into account the time required to read the strings from disk, or the network, etc. The extra complication in the code just doesn't seem worthwhile.

Comment: @JimMischel As Andreas's benchmark suggested it looks like arrays are the way to go. I'll see if I can get something up and running and get back with results and undoubtedly more questions.

Comment: Array solution does take up more memory, but then again, if you've already used 200 Mb for the input string, using 256 Kb for the array is nothing. Unless of course you can process the input characters as you read them.

Comment: You can as well use `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap` and get a sorted collection in one loop. I.e. it looks like N + NlogN for a `HashMap` solution, and it should be just NlogN for a `TreeMap` one.

Comment: @Andreas by Kb, did you mean kB, or perhaps KiB? While there's no uppercase K in the set of SI prefixes (although the [Ki- prefix by IEC uses uppercase K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)), both b and B exist and mean different things. Kb would be kelvin-bits.

Comment: @bashnesnos: Actually, the hashmap solution is N+k log k, where N is the string length and k is the number of unique characters. Treemap solution is N log k.

Comment: @jandvorak: K has been used in the computer industry to mean 2^10 for at least 40 years. Whether it's "officially" recognized, I don't know, but every programmer I've ever worked with understands it, just as they understand that MB means 2^20 bytes.

Comment: @JimMischel I meant just filling the `HashMap` and sorting it afterwards would take K + K*logK, and it would be just K*logK for the `TreeSet`. In total it would be N + K + K*logK for the `HashMap` solution and N + K*logK for the `TreeSet` solution. So we are saving a loop on K.

Comment: @bashnesnos Your [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783311/39784284#comment66868104_39783566) was about *replacing* `HashMap` with `TreeMap`, and your [last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783311/39784284#comment66922168_39783566) is about `TreeSet`, which cannot be used to replace `HashMap`, so what are you talking about? If you're referring to [your suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783311/39784284#comment66868611_39784284) to my answer, then you're replacing `ArrayList` with `TreeSet` (way different), and it doesn't work (see my comment).

Comment: @Andreas I agree it's totally messed up; I just wanted to suggest replacing whatever is used as a temporary structure for sorting with a tree-based structure to do insertion and sorting in one go. In case of the original answer that would be `HashMap` vs `TreeMap` and in case of your test cases it is `ArrayList` vs `TreeSet`. As per your comment it won't be possible to replace `HashMap` with `TreeMap` and a composite key would be required as well, so it's `HashMap` vs `TreeSet` as well.

Comment: @bashnesnos: I don't know the specifics of `TreeMap` performance. Whereas inserting `k` items into the `TreeMap` is indeed O(k log k), the constant factors might make it slower than the O(k + k log k) of inserting into an `ArrayList` and then sorting. If `k` is really large, I'd expect the `ArrayList` approach to be faster. If `k` is small, I would not be surprised to see the `TreeMap` solution be faster.

Comment: @JimMischel totally agree with you that `TreeMap` requires more housekeeping than an `ArrayList` and it depends.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: This is not an answer, but simply showing performance test code of answers by [Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39783566/5221149) and [Óscar López](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39783734/5221149) (with parallel streams in response to [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783311/efficiently-sorting-a-string-by-the-number-of-occurances-of-each-of-its-characte?noredirect=1#comment66862159_39783311)).*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String s = buildString();
        System.out.println("buildString: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String result1 = testUsingArray(s);
        System.out.println("testUsingArray: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String result2 = testUsingMap(s);
        System.out.println("testUsingMap: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String result3 = testUsingStream(s);
        System.out.println("testUsingStream: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String result4 = testUsingParallelStream(s);
        System.out.println("testUsingParallelStream: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        System.out.println(result1);
        System.out.println(result2);
        System.out.println(result3);
        System.out.println(result4);
    }
    private static String buildString() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        char[] buf = new char[100_000_000];
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
            buf[i] = (char)(rnd.nextInt(127 - 33) + 33);
        return new String(buf);
    }
    private static String testUsingArray(String s) {
        int[] count = new int[65536];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            count[s.charAt(i)]++;
        List<CharCount> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
            if (count[i] != 0)
                list.add(new CharCount((char)i, count[i]));
        Collections.sort(list);
        char[] buf = new char[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
            buf[i] = list.get(i).ch;
        return new String(buf);
    }
    private static String testUsingMap(String s) {
        Map<Character, CharCount> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            map.computeIfAbsent(s.charAt(i), CharCount::new).count++;
        List<CharCount> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(list);
        char[] buf = new char[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
            buf[i] = list.get(i).ch;
        return new String(buf);
    }
    private static String testUsingStream(String s) {
        int[] output = s.codePoints()
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                        .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                        .toArray();
        return new String(output, 0, output.length);
    }
    private static String testUsingParallelStream(String s) {
        int[] output = s.codePoints()
                        .parallel()
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                        .entrySet()
                        .parallelStream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                        .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                        .toArray();
        return new String(output, 0, output.length);
    }
}
class CharCount implements Comparable<CharCount> {
    final char ch;
    int count;
    CharCount(char ch) {
        this.ch = ch;
    }
    CharCount(char ch, int count) {
        this.ch = ch;
        this.count = count;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(CharCount that) {
        return Integer.compare(that.count, this.count); // descending
    }
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
buildString: 974ms
testUsingArray: 48ms
testUsingMap: 216ms
testUsingStream: 1279ms
testUsingParallelStream: 442ms
UOMP<FV{KHt`(-q6;Gl'R9nxy+.Y[=2a7^45v?E@e,>|AD_\ILpJ}8sow"Z&bCmNW1$!Sd0c]~g3BjX#fz:Q*Tkui%/r)h
UOMP<FV{KHt`(-q6;Gl'R9nxy+.Y[=2a7^45v?E@e,>|AD_\ILpJ}8sow"Z&bCmNW1$!Sd0c]~g3BjX#fz:Q*Tkui%/r)h
UOMP<FV{KHt`(-q6;Gl'R9nxy+.Y[=2a7^45v?E@e,>|AD_\ILpJ}8sow"Z&bCmNW1$!Sd0c]~g3BjX#fz:Q*Tkui%/r)h
UOMP<FV{KHt`(-q6;Gl'R9nxy+.Y[=2a7^45v?E@e,>|AD_\ILpJ}8sow"Z&bCmNW1$!Sd0c]~g3BjX#fz:Q*Tkui%/r)h
```

Comment: Another test case for you regarding using TreeSet instead of ArrayList: private static String testUsingTreeSet(String s) {
        int[] count = new int[65536];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            count[s.charAt(i)]++;
        Set<CharCount> set = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
            if (count[i] != 0)
                set.add(new CharCount((char)i, count[i]));

        char[] buf = new char[set.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (CharCount chcnt : set)
            buf[i++] = chcnt.ch;
        return new String(buf);
    }

Comment: I would expect the `TreeSet` solution to be somewhat slower than the `HashSet` solution. The `TreeSet` solution is O(n log k), where n is the length of the string and k is number of unique characters. The `HashSet` solution (and the array solution) are O(n + k log k) (n to populate the `HashSet` and then k log k to sort the items). Seeing as how n in this case is orders of magnitude larger than k, (10^8 vs 6x10^4), you can consider the `HashSet` solution to be O(n).

Comment: @JimMischel a test for an 100000000 string shows the same timings for the `TreeSet` and the `HashSet`(`ArrayList` insert is O(n) as well). Since we're calculating the worst case, it would be O(N + K + K logK) for the `ArrayList` (N for traversing the input, K for filling the map/arrayList and K logK for sorting). For the `TreeSet` it would be just O(N + K logK), we're not changing the N part here at all, we're just change the way we sort the invidual char counts. Actually, we could as well just sort the array after the N part with `Arrays.sort` and don't use extra list/map at all.

Comment: @bashnesnos: I see. I misunderstood your proposed approach.

Comment: @bashnesnos You solution doesn't work, *unless* you change the `compareTo()` implementation to do secondary ordering on `ch`, which you haven't proposed to do. `TreeSet` doesn't allow duplicates, but `ArrayList` and `sort()` both do (retaining original order). If multiple characters occur equally often, i.e. have the same `count`, `TreeSet` would only keep the last character with that count.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the `compareTo()` implementation needs to be changed to make it work and I forgot it.
        public int compareTo(CharCount that) {
            int compare = Integer.compare(that.count, this.count);
            return compare == 0 ? Character.compare(that.ch, this.ch) : compare; // descending
        }
It's still interesting to compare those.

Comment: @bashnesnos: Just sorting the array of counts could be rather expensive, depending on its size. Sorting an array of 65,536 values could take a lot longer than scanning it to select the few (hunderd?) non-zero items and then sorting those.

Comment: @JimMischel correct, but those 65,536 values are mostly zeroes, i.e. already sorted anyway; so it won't be a big difference due to timsort adaption used for `Arrays.sort` - it would be pretty much like the same scanning most of the time. In the worst-case just array approach would be much faster though since we're not copying data, and it's anyway `Arrays.sort` under the hood of the `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun (and I'm not claiming this is the most efficient solution): how about some Java 8 lambdas + parallel streams?

```
public String sortByCharacterOccurrencesAndTrim(String str) {

    // build a frequency map, for each code point store its count    
    Map<Integer, Long> frequencies =
        str.codePoints()
           .parallel()
           .boxed()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    // sort by descending frequency and collect code points into array
    int[] output =
        frequencies.entrySet()
                   .parallelStream()
                   .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                   .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                   .toArray();

    // create output string from code point array
    return new String(output, 0, output.length);

}
```

If you want a super-efficient solution you can rewrite the above algorithm using explicit loops, but that's a lot of code and it's late for me :) . The idea, however, will be the same: build a char frequency map, sort by frequency using descending order and build a string with the chars.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more consistent to use `str.codePoints()`?

Comment: @shmosel would there be any advantage?

Comment: It would allow for 3 or 4 byte characters, not that it's necessary here. But if you're using the code point constructor, you may as well use the corresponding stream method.

Comment: @shmosel fair enough :) I updated my answer with your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @Andreas great work! I took the liberty of updating my answer for using parallel streams, the performance improvement is greater than I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about streams and lambdas, but I would do something like this:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map;
for (int i=0;i<str.length,i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    switch(c){
        case: map.containsKey(c):
            int temp = map.get(c)++;
            map.put(c, tmp);
            break;
        case: !map.containsKey(c):
            map.put(c, tmp);
            break;
    }
}
```

to count the occurrences. Then it's just a matter of sorting it from highest to lowest afterwards.

Comment: Does that even compile? I would think you'd need `map.put(c, 1);`

Comment: there are errors on lines (starting from zero) 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 in this answer